# Which remote file system can be used on Linux without occupying local space?

Tags: debian, filesystems, mount, webdav, davfs2

I want to extend my server's local disk on Debian 6.0 by mounting a remote file system.

But I don't want to have this remote file system to occupy (too much) local disk space, for instance with caches etc.

On my remote server which offers the additional disk space I have access to protocols like WebDAV, xFTPx, SMB/CIFS, SCP.

I tried davfs2, but it seems that this is copying the files between the client and server (like Dropbox does), which I want to avoid.

Comment: Your question may get closed, but here's a hint: NFS.

Answer (score 2):

WebDAV.

You can use it with small cache.

change your 
/etc/davfs2/davfs2.conf

```
...
cache_dir       /var/cache/davfs2 # system wide cache
cache_size      1                # MiByte
```

and you will able to upload any file to webdav storage and you can copy from webdav dir any files.

I have a VPS with 2gb drive space. And using 10gb webdav folder with it.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend sshfs. So many online examples: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/sshfs

Something like:

```
$ sshfs bob@myserver:/home/bob /mnt/bob
```